# Is this 'Ant Killer' effective to kill carpet moth?

Tags: wooden-furniture, carpet, maintenance, insect

I've noticed a few moth flying around a carpeted area as well as some possibly larvae. I already have this ant killer powder and wondering if it would be effective for the moth and other insects?

[image: ant killer]

The other product from the same manufacturer is [this carpet moth killer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Rentokil-Carpet-Beetle-Killer-Powder/dp/B00GOXOCQU) but I notice that one has also got permethrin same as the ant killer. So I'm wondering if it's just a marketing scam or are they actually different in the ingredients and effectiveness towards different insects and eggs?

Comment: Why did this go on hold? :-/

Comment: Asking about specific products is off-topic here as the close reason above explains. The community may find it on topic if the question is only about what active chemicals are needed in a pesticide for killing moths, but even that may be getting outside of the expertise of the members on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to find a good fogger and fog the van. Sprays and powders typically only work on the ones you can see.

As to the different products, it's important to note that many insect poisons share the same active ingredient, but at different concentrations. Ants are orders of magnitude smaller than moths, so it could be that this powder is more than sufficient to kill ants and eggs, but is ineffective against adult moths.

It's also possible this is just marketing as well. In other words, you market the same product, but label it for the different insects that people want to kill. If I have a moth problem, I'm not necessarily going to buy something labeled for ants.

Comment: One other difference is that they may contain different attractants, which could make them effective for one collection of insects but not another.

Comment: The hardware stores have no clue what a fogger is. Would this work as a fogger or should I wait and get it online? https://cl.ly/kivw

Comment: @Neeku Something like [this insect fogger](https://www.amazon.com/JOHNSON-74251-Fogger-3-Pack-1-5-Ounce/dp/B00CHT4BKM)

Comment: Oh I found what you meant but I mean the local stores don't have that. Was wondering if that 'space' spare could do the job so that I don't wait for the fogger.